# Can a busy or under-resourced Windows Small Business Server 2003 cause momentary client disconnects?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I deal with an application which runs on network clients, and opens many database files from a network share. This is a flat-file-type database, as opposed to SQL Server or whatever.

We have a couple of Windows Small Business Server 2003 sites who get thrown out of this application quite regularly, due to actual or perceived temporary network disconnections.

On both sites I have heard mutterings from the companies that handle their hardware support about SBS 2003 doing this if it gets busy enough or low enough on memory. Certainly on one site they are running at about 6% free RAM on the server due to SQL Server 2005 inhaling it all.

Could this be the case ?

Answer (score 1):

It's (always) worth limiting the amount of RAM that the SQL instances of WSUS and Monitoring on SBS 2003 can use. (Default is a couple of GB for each!)

From a command prompt:

```
osql -E -S ServerName\WSUS
```

Replace 'Servername' with name of your server.

Then enter each line below separately.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure with override
go    
sp_configure 'max server memory',128
reconfigure with override
go
```

Repeat above using Servername\Monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be the case - I experienced this in my network. You have to check logfiles to be sure. Tons of RAM are always welcome on busy servers.